# Most efficient way to split paragraph based on element height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is the most efficient way to dynamically split a very long HTML paragraph element into smaller paragraphs of a given height?

The function below (jQuery) recursively chops out one word at a time from the text, checks the new length, and stops when the text is broken down into acceptably small chunks.

```
function split_par(element, max_height)
{
  if (element.height() <= max_height)
    return;
  var array = element.text().split(" ");
  var pos = 0;
  while (element.height () > max_height)
  {
    pos -= 1;
    element.html("<p>" + array.slice(0,pos).join(" ") + "</p>");
  }
  var next_par = element.clone();
  next_par.html("<p>" + array.slice(pos).join(" ") + "</p>");
  $('body').append(next_par);
  split_par(next_par, max_height);
}
```

This is inefficient and take a long time, but it's the most reliable method I've found. I'm sure there's a better way. I'm also not familiar with Javascript or jQuery, so any general tips on the code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps placing the text in container elements (Eg. divs) and using something like [Jquery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) would do the trick.